# why I can't sendFile() in node.js express when deployed to AWS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I am using node.js express to serve some static file like svg and json to the client, so I used sendFile() to send the files directly.

so here is my server file structures,

```
/root    // the root of the server
   /maps    // put some static files
     /routes/api     // put the web API
```

in the web API

```
app.get('/buildings/map',function(req,res){
    var mappath = 'maps/ARM-MAP_Base.svg';
        res.sendfile(mappath);
})
```

It works perfectly on my local server to send files to the client, so it means the  server could locate the file and send it. but when the server is deployed to the AWS, this methods would encounter a error - 242:Error: ENOENT, stat node.js, looks like it can't open the file in that path

I read some solutions like combining the __dirname with mappath, it didn't work since it would bring to the path of /routes/api/maps/...

so far I have no idea why it works on my local computer but fail to work on the AWS

Answer (score 0):

Relative `fs` paths like `mappath` will be resolved from the [current working directory](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd), which isn't guaranteed to be consistent. It works locally because you're executing your application with `/root` as your working directory.

This is why you're finding recommendations to use `__dirname`, which an be used to resolve paths relative to the current script.

Though, along with it, you'll want to use `../` to [resolve parent directories](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to).

```
var mappath = 'maps/ARM-MAP_Base.svg';
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/../../../' + mappath);
```

This assumes the current script is located in and `__dirname` would be `/root/maps/routes/api` as the indentation in your directory tree suggests.